# Preciso fazer a somar de uma celular de uma tabela html dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ola estou com um código gostaria que ele fizesse a soma entre as célula de uma tabela e exibisse abaixo no total conforme o código abaixo.

-mais gostaria dinamicamente conforme for adicionando uma outra coluna abaixo do produtos sem que tenha que alterar o javascript.

Segue o meu código de exemplo, alguém dar essa forca aqui pro amigo desde já agradeço ! `

```js
 
      
      
      var confirma = document.getElementById("btn-confirma");
      var cancela = document.getElementById("btn-cancela");
      var enviar = document.getElementById("btn-enviarpedido");
      var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

      var snack = document.getElementById("snack");
      var load = document.getElementById("load");
      var cadastro = document.getElementById("cadastro");

      var soma_13 = document.getElementById("soma-13");
      var subtrai_13 = document.getElementById("subtrai-13");
    
      var soma_8 = document.getElementById("soma-8");
      var subtrai_8 = document.getElementById("subtrai-8");
      var nome;
      var fone;

      

      var intervalo;
      var qtdade_8 = 0;
      var qtdade_13 = 0;
      var preco_13= 54.10;
      var preco_8 = 17.20;
      var total = 0.00;
      
      (function(){
         document.getElementById("preco-8").innerHTML = "R$ " + preco_8.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
         document.getElementById("preco-13").innerHTML = "R$ " + preco_13.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
      })();

      soma_13.addEventListener("click", function(){
         qtdade_13 = qtdade_13 + 1;
            AtualizaDados();
      },false );

      subtrai_13.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(qtdade_13 > 0) qtdade_13 = qtdade_13 - 1;
            AtualizaDados();
      },false );

      soma_8.addEventListener("click", function(){
         qtdade_8 = qtdade_8 + 1;
            AtualizaDados();
      },false );

      subtrai_8.addEventListener("click", function(){
         if(qtdade_8 > 0) qtdade_8 = qtdade_8 - 1;
          AtualizaDados();
      },false );
      
      
      confirma.addEventListener("click", function(){
         //snack.className = 'confirmacao animation-snack';
         nome =  document.getElementById("nome").value;
         fone =  document.getElementById("telefone").value;

   
   
  
         
                  document.getElementById("qtd-13").value = qtdade_13;
                  document.getElementById("qtd-8").value = qtdade_8;
                  document.getElementById("pre-13").value = preco_13;
                  document.getElementById("pre-8").value = preco_8;
                  document.getElementById("tot").value = total;
               cadastro.style.display = "none";
               load.style.display = "block";
               load.className = 'loading animation-load';

               intervalo = setInterval(function(){
                  finalizaPedido();
               },3000);


      },false );

      enviar.addEventListener("click", function(){
         console.log(load);
         cadastro.style.display = "block";
      },false );

      cancela.addEventListener("click", function(){
         cadastro.style.display = "none";

      },false );

function fone(campo){
         if (campo.value.length == 0){
         campo.value = "(" + campo.value; }
         if (campo.value.length == 3){
         campo.value = campo.value + ") "; }
         if (campo.value.length == 10){
         campo.value = campo.value + "-";}
      }

function finalizaPedido(){
   clearInterval(intervalo);
   console.log("Finalizando");
   load.className ='loading animation-load-back';
   snack.className = 'confirmacao animation-snack';
   enviar.style.display ="none";
   document.getElementById("check").innerHTML  = " <img src='check_256.png'  style='width: 40px;height: 40px;'/>";
  
   formulario.submit();
}

function AtualizaDados(){
      document.getElementById("qtdade-13").innerHTML = qtdade_13;
      document.getElementById("qtdade-8").innerHTML = qtdade_8;

      total = (qtdade_8 * preco_8) + (qtdade_13 * preco_13);
      document.getElementById("soma-total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');

 }
```

```css
*{
 font-family: "sans-serif";
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
html{
 height: 100%;
}
body{
 
 min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h1{
 font-family: "sans-serif";
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: 700;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 /*text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;*/
}
.header{
  background: #212121;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.content{
 background: #F5F5F5;
 flex: 1;
}

.content table tr td{
 /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}

.footer{
  background: #212121;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.style1{
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.style2{
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #FFF; 

}
.style3{
 color: green;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #FFF;  
 font-weight: 700; 
}
.style4{
 color: #212121;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; 
 padding: 7px;
}
.ui-btj table{
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 10px; 
 padding-right: 10px; 
}
.ui-btj table tr td{
 height: 50px;
 margin: 2px;
 background: #e3e3e3;
}

.footer table td{
 padding: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-btn-corner{
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px;

}

.ui-btn{
 background: #FEDE02;
 padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-btn:hover{
 background: #FEA002;
}

.ui-btn-up{
 background: #F5F5F5;
 padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 border: 3px solid #ccc;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-btn-up:hover{
 background: #FEDE02;
}

li{
 
 background: #eBeBeB;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 line-height: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ddd ;
}
img{
 width: 65px;
 height: 90px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 5px;
}

.btj-comando{
 min-width: 90px; 
}
.btj-comando table{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.btj-comando table tr td{
 height: 15px;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-top-color: #989898;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;

}
@keyframes spin { 
  100% { 
    transform: rotate(360deg); 
  } 
} 

.loading{
 width: 200px;
 height: 110px;
 background: #dedede;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 left:20%;
 top: 25%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -0px 0px 32px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 32px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 display: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}

.form{
margin:0% 0% 0% 20%;

 width: 200px;
 height: 130px;
 background: #dedede;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 top: 25%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -0px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45); 
 display: none;
}
#cadastro table tr td{
 height: 25px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.ui-btn-form{
 color: #525252;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.confirma:hover{
 color: blue;
}
.cancela:hover{
 color: red;
}
.form input{
 margin: 0px;
}
label{
 font-size: 12px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.confirmacao{
 width: 300px;
 height: 30px;
 background: #525353;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 top: 60%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -0px 0px 55px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 55px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: none;
}
.animation-snack{
 display: block;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-name: slideup;
}


.animation-load-back{
 display: block;
 -webkit-animation: slidedownload 1s forwards;
     animation: slidedownload 1s forwards;
}

input{
 height: 20px;
}
@keyframes slideup{
 from{
  top: 100%;
 }
  to{
   top: 60%; 
  }
}

@keyframes slideupload{
 from{
  top: 100%;
 }
  to{
    top: 40%;
  }
}

@keyframes slidedownload{
 from{
  top: 40%;
 }
  to{
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
}

.error{
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 color: red;
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
      <h1 >PEDIDO DE GAS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <ul>
       <li>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td >
                  <img src="13.png" alt="">      
              </td>
             <td  width="80%" class="ui-btj">
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" ><span class="style3">13kg</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center"><span class="style4" id="preco-13">R$ 0,00</span></td>
                    </tr>
               </table>

                
              </td>
              <td  class="btj-comando">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ui-btn-up" id="soma-13">+</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="style4" id="qtdade-13">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ui-btn-up" id="subtrai-13" >-</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          
          
       </li>
       <li>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td >
                  <img src="8.png" alt="">      
              </td>
             <td  width="80%" class="ui-btj">
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" ><span class="style3">8kg</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center"><span class="style4" id="preco-8">R$ 0,00</span></td>
                    </tr>
               </table>

                
              </td>
              <td class="btj-comando">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ui-btn-up" id="soma-8">+</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="style4" id="qtdade-8">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ui-btn-up" id="subtrai-8">-</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          
          
       </li>
       
     </ul>
  </div>

<div class="loading" id="load">
  
        <div class="circle"></div>
          <div align="center"><br>
              <span>Processando seu Pedido</span>
          </div>
</div>

<form id="formulario" action="teste.php" method="post">
  <div class="form" id="cadastro">
      <input type="hidden" id='qtd-13' name='qtd-13' value="teste1">
      <input type="hidden" id='pre-13' name='pre-13'>
      <input type="hidden" id='qtd-8' name='qtd-8'>
      <input type="hidden" id='pre-8' name='pre-8'>
       <input type="hidden" id='tot' name='tot'>
      <table >
        <tr>
          <span class="error" id="error"></span>
        </tr>
        <tr >
         
          <td colspan="2">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>  
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" >
          </td>

        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <label for="telefone">Fone</label> 
             <input placeholder="(97) 9999-9999" name="telefone" onkeypress="fone(this);" maxlength="16" type="text"  id="telefone">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="ui-btn-form cancela" align="center" id="btn-cancela">Cancela</td>
          <td class="ui-btn-form confirma" align="center" id="btn-confirma">Confirma</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</form>
  <div class="confirmacao" id="snack">
  
          <span>Pedido Enviado Com sucesso...</span>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
      <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="49%">
                <div align="center">
                  <span class="style1">TOTAL</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="51%">
                  <div align="center" class="style2">
                    ENTREGAMOS ATÈ AS 18:00 HS
                  </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="49%">
                <div align="center">
                  <span class="style1">R$</span>
                   <span class="style1" id="soma-total">0,00</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="51%" id="check" align="center">
                    <div align="center" class="ui-btn-corner">
                      <span class="ui-btn" id="btn-enviarpedido">
                        <span>
                           Enviar Pedido
                        </span>
                        
                       </span>
                    </div>
                   
              </td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </footer>
</body>
```

`

Comment: O que exatamente você quer somar? Não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Isso que eu altere apenas mais uma linha ou seja mais um produto apenas na tabela sem ter necessidade de alterar o javascrtip

Comment: Sugestão, tenta escrever melhor a descrição da tua pergunta. Você postou aparentemente todo o seu código, mas não foi nenhum pouco preciso quanto ao problema.

Comment: porque os produtos e valores vem do meu banco de dados entendeu

Comment: Desculpa vou alterar e porque não conheço muito de jquery e nem javascript peco perdão por isso !

Comment: Não deu pra entender. Recomendo clicar em "editar" na tua pergunta, e sem pressa, explica desde o começo, o que sua aplicação faz exatamente, o que ela deveria fazer e não faz, como somar células da tabela vai te ajudar exatamente, quais células você quer somar  e quando quer somar.

Comment: Ok estou verificando como fazer a pergunta mais direta desde ja agradeco vc por me ajudar

Comment: Ok alterado espero muito que me entenda !

Comment: Gostaria de somar conforme for adicionando mais e menos de cada produto na lista

Comment: Mas isso já não está funcionando? Cliquei em executar no código postado na tua pergunta e aparentemente está funcionando.

Comment: isso esta funcionado mais cada vez que eu for adicionar um novo produto e necessário que eu altere o javascript, eu preciso que ele seja dinâmico porque vou buscar as informações vindo de um banco de dados em uma lista.

Comment: Vai ser necessário alterar muita coisa nesse código para ficar dinâmico. A começar pelo preço dos produtos que em vez de variáveis deverão ficar em um array ou objeto JSON. Segundo que você vai ter que criar uma única função para o evento de adicionar produtos de qualquer botão. Use o atributo "data" no botão e adicione ali o identificador do produto. Assim você poderá recuperar no Evento....

Comment: Recomendo que de uma olhada em um tutorial básico de JQuery, pois vai facilitar muito sua vida.

Comment: O código consegui no Control C  rsrs mais como não manjo muito de jquery vai ficar pra proxima  desde ja agradeço  a coomprençao ai de todos tenho que estudar mais obrigado vou colocar como resolvido

Comment: No aguardo ainda de uma luz no fim do túnel não consegui ainda resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camarada, segue uma base para te ajudar.
Entendi a sua idéia em não ter que editar o java-script, para tanto foi necessário concatenar um id com um nome fixo para detectar os ids de html utilizados.

Na hora que você gerar o html com php(dentro de um loop pegando id, nome_produto e preco ):

```
        <!-- Bloco gerado por PHP -->
        <tr>
            <td class="prodtd">

                <div id="nome<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="nomeprod"> <?php echo $nome_produto; ?></div>

                <div id="preco<?php echo $id; ?>" class="preco">    <?php echo $preco; ?></div>

            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">

                <input type="button" value="-" onclick="remove(<?php echo $id; ?>)"> 

                <span id="qtd<?php echo $id; ?>">0</span> 

                <input type="button" value="+" onclick="adiciona(<?php echo $id; ?>)">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Fim Bloco gerado por PHP -->
```

Abaixo segue código de exemplo funcionando:

```js
// java-script

total = 0;
        
        function adiciona(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"adicao");
        }
        
        function remove(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"subtracao");
        }    
            
        function calcula(id,operacao)
        {
                nomeid  = "nome"+id;
                precoid = "preco"+id;
                qtdid   = "qtd"+id;
                
                nome  = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
                
                preco = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;    
                preco = parseInt(preco);
                
                qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
                qtd   = parseInt(qtd);

                //Debug
                //alert("Produto: " + nome + "\n Preço: " + preco);    
                
                if(operacao=="adicao")
                {
                    total = total + preco;
                    qtd = qtd + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    total = total - preco;
                    qtd = qtd - 1;
                }
                
                document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML = qtd;
                
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        }
```

```css
/* css */
        div {text-align:center;}
        table {  border-collapse: collapse; border:1px solid #777; width:500px; margin:auto; }
        .prodtd { width:380px; height:80px; }
        .nomeprod { background-color:#ffa;}
        .preco { background-color:#eee;}
```

```html
    <body>

        <table>
        
            <!-- Bloco gerado por PHP -->
            <tr>
                <td class="prodtd">
                
                    <div id="nome1"     class="nomeprod">Nome Prod 1</div>
                    
                    <div id="preco1" class="preco">10</div>
                    
                </td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                
                    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="remove(1)"> 
                    
                    <span id="qtd1">0</span> 
                    
                    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="adiciona(1)">
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Fim Bloco gerado por PHP -->
            
            
            
            <!-- Bloco gerado por PHP -->
            <tr>
                <td class="prodtd">
                
                    <div id="nome2"     class="nomeprod">Nome Prod 2</div>
                    
                    <div id="preco2" class="preco">22</div>
                    
                </td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                
                    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="remove(2)"> 
                    
                    <span id="qtd2">0</span> 
                    
                    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="adiciona(2)">
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Fim Bloco gerado por PHP -->        
            
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><b>Total: <span id="total">0<span></b></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        


    </body>
```

**Para coletar os valores e passar para o PHP:**

```
<script>
    function verifica_e_envia()
    {
        array_dados = new Array();

        colecao = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        qtd_blocos = colecao.length - 1; // O último tr da tabela é onde fica o total e está sendo descontado
        // É necessário saber a quantidade de blocos para poder usar em um loop catando os valores

        // Percorre os blocos catando nomes, quantidades e valores dos produtos com quantidade maior que zero
        for(i=1; i<=qtd_blocos ;i++)
        {
            qtdid = "qtd"+i;
            qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
            qtd   = parseInt(qtd);

            if(qtd>0)
            {
                obj_tmp = {};

                nomeid = "nome"+i;
                nome   = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;

                precoid = "preco"+i;
                preco   = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;
                preco   = parseInt(preco);

                obj_tmp.nome  = nome;
                obj_tmp.preco = preco;
                obj_tmp.qtd   = qtd;
                obj_tmp.subtotal = qtd*preco;

                // adiciona elemento no array de dados que será enviado
                array_dados.push(obj_tmp);
            }
        }

        // põe o array_dados no input hidden json_dados
        document.getElementById("json_dados").value = JSON.stringify(array_dados);

        // envia o formulário form_pedido_produtos
        document.getElementById("form_pedido_produtos").submit();

    }
</script>        

<form action="pedido_produtos.php" method="post" id="form_pedido_produtos" >
    <input type="hidden" name="json_dados" id="json_dados">        
    <input type="button" value="Verifica e envia valores" onclick="verifica_e_envia()">
</form>
```

Para ler os dados no PHP (pedido_produtos.php):

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST["json_dados"])) die("Post não enviado.");

$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);

//var_dump($array_dados);

$total = 0;

foreach($array_dados as $obj)
{
    echo 'Nome: '. $obj->nome . '<br>';
    echo 'Preço: '. $obj->preco . '<br>';    
    echo 'Quantidade: '. $obj->qtd . '<br>';        
    echo 'Subtotal: '. $obj->subtotal . '<br>';    

    echo '<br><br>';

    $total = $total + $obj->subtotal;
}

echo 'Total: '.$total;
```

**Output na tela após enviar o formulário, adicionando 4 produtos "Nome Prod 1" e 5 produtos "Nome Prod 2":**

```
Nome: Nome Prod 1
Preço: 10
Quantidade: 4
Subtotal: 40

Nome: Nome Prod 2
Preço: 22
Quantidade: 5
Subtotal: 110

Total: 150
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54636/discussion-on-answer-by-antonio-alexandre-preciso-fazer-a-somar-de-uma-celular-d)